# I have to rebuild the Jar everytime I change the property file under src/main/resources

Tags: java, gradle

I have a property file under src/main/resources/db.properties and every time I change the value I have to rebuild the Jar. is there a solution where I don't have to do that?

Comment: How are you running the JAR?  If the properties file is part of the JAR then you will need to repackage it regardless.

Comment: once the Jar is built by gradle I just run java -jar filename.jar so yes I am assuming it is part of the Jar. how do I repackage it in a way that when the property file changes I dont have to rebuild the jar?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid rebuilding the JAR although you might be able to avoid rebuilding your Java source files.  A JAR is just an archive, and if a component changes you will have to repackage.

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is located in src/main/resources (Assuming the default layout, which can be changed, of course), it is copied in the processResources task (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).
That means it is part of the jar file - and changing it requires you to repackage the jar file if you want the java application to pick up the change. I don't see a way around there, other than having the file separate from the jar file and accessing it via regular file api. (or accessing the jar content via zip tools  and making the changes available to the runtime afterwards.. and dealing with locked files.. yeah, no.)

Gradle is intelligent enough not to fire the whole build process every time, only when things change.
If you want to manually "skip" the compiling and only repackage the jar file, you'd probably have to add your own tasks to the build.gradle. Simply running "just" the jar task will not do then, as that depends on the compile task.